# Docker build failed: add-apt-repository -y ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin

Tags: docker

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:rolling

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install bitcoin-qt
```

Whe I run `docker build -t test .` it's failing because of:
(the output is when I defined seperate RUN steps so I could easily define where it was going wrong).

```
Step 5/11 : RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
 ---> Running in fc64322d6d04
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpxbk1iw0_/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: End of file
Failed to add key.
The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository -y ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What am I missing? I'm not behind a proxy.

Comment: Try running your docker file manually and check what happens at that step. That command is probably an interactive one, and it hangs because it is receiving no answer during the build.

Comment: @whites11 Hi, it's really exiting the build with zero-code 1.

Comment: Have you tried running the commands manually?

Comment: @whites11, No but I'm not on an ubuntu system.

Comment: You can use docker. `docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:rolling bash` . From the shell run the commands you have in your Dockerfile in sequence and check what happens

Comment: I did it: just the same error at the end: keyserver receive failed: End of file
Failed to add key.

Comment: Ok let me try a thing

Comment: Fun fact, it worked for me! Ensure you have the latest ubuntu:rolling image with `docker pull ubuntu:rolling` and try again.

Comment: @whites11 lol, works too on my mac osx, but not inside my Centos7 (VM)